# $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers $x+y+21=3xy$. Find maximum possible integral power of $6$ in $(xy)$!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

How should I solve this question?
I am getting three pairs $3,3 ; 11,1 ; 1,11$.

Can there be any other pairs and why?
I am not able to reason out that this are the only three pairs.

Comment: Try the pairs: $$3,3, \to (3.3)!=9!\\1,11 \to (1.11)!$$ now $$9!=2^7.3^3Q=(2^3.3^3)Q'=6^3Q'$$and $$11!=2^7.3^3k=(2^3.3^3)k'=6^3k'$$so $$6^3|9! ,\\6^3|11!$$

Comment: Can there be any other pairs from what i mentioned

Comment: You said that you got 3 pairs!

Comment: Apart from those three pairs can there exist any other pair ; i am not able to reason out that this are the only three pairs

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$1+63=(3x-1)(3y-1)$$

Now what are the positive divisors$(\equiv-1\pmod3)$ of $64?$

Comment: 3,3 ; 11,1 ; 1,11

Comment: How is this relevant

Comment: @Manan, Now check which combination gives the max?

Comment: 11,1 gives the max

Comment: But my query is can there be any other pairs  i am not able to reason out that this are the only three pairs

Comment: @Manan, $3x-1$ has to be a positive integer, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since $3xy$ grows a lot faster than $x+y+21$, we can bound the possible solutions. Assume $x\leq y$, then

$$3xy =x+y+21 \leq 2y+21$$

$$(3x-2)y \leq 21$$

If $x\geq 4$, it forces $y$ to be less than $x$, contradicting our assumption.  So $x$ can take only the values $1, 2,$ or $3$.  You have all the pairs.